# Best numerical method for solving ODEs with periodic solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

Say I have a system of ODEs
$$
\dot{x} = f(x,y,t), \\
\dot{y} = g(x,y,t).
$$
In this case given by the stream function $\psi(x,y,t)$ i.e $(\dot{x}, \dot{y}) = (-\partial_y\psi, \partial_x\psi) = (f, g)$, and we know the trajectories follow periodic orbits.

What numerical method would result in stable periodic orbits, if I were to plot said trajectories?

Comment: I would think finite elements would give you periodic orbits, because you can implement the periodic boundary conditions exactly. Shooting methods based on your method of choice would likely do reasonably well, also. To some extent, the quality of the shooting method would depend on how well-behaved $f$ and $g$ are.

Comment: Or use the BVP solver of your software package. Most likely it will use a multiple shooting method based on some implicit integration method with a variable subdivision, simplifying one might say that this uses a finite-element method.

Answer (score 3):

For such a system of equations, which to me looks Hamiltonian (maybe the explicit dependence of $\psi$ on $t$ could make things a bit more difficult), the best class of methods is the one of *symplectic integrators*, which are a subfamily of the Runge-Kutta methods. Most of them are implicit, but if your Hamiltonian $\psi$ has a specific structure (i.e., separable), then you have explicit alternatives.

In particular, symplectic methods have the favorable property of (almost) conserving the energy over long time spans, thus resulting in orbits which are stable over time. The standard explicit Euler will make your energy explose, and the implicit Euler will make it implode.

Specifically, a symplectic method of order 1 is the so-called symplectic Euler method. For order 2, you have a wider choice. For example, implicit midpoint is symplectic, as well as the Störmer-Verlet method. The best reference around for symplectic methods (and geometric integration in general) is the book *Geometric numerical integration: Structure-preserving algorithms for Ordinary Differential Equations* by E. Hairer, C. Lubich and G. Wanner (Springer). Chapter VI is dedicated exclusively to the problem you're dealing with.

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately the Hamiltonian is non-separable, so the methods presented in Geometric numerical integration are all implicit for this problem. Could you suggest a symplectic method that works for non-separable Hamiltonians?

Comment: To my knowledge, there are no easy-to-implement (i.e., same level as Runge-Kutta) explicit symplectic integrators for non-separable Hamiltonian systems. Nonetheless, often these periodic systems are non-stiff in the diffusive sense. Hence, fixed point iterations should converge quite fast for implicit methods. If I were you, I would go for any Gauss method (implicit midpoint), implemented with fixed point iterations to solve the nonlinear system. It should be fast and it doesn't require the Jacobian of the r.h.s. to be implemented.